# Lightning component not getting on load value

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, aura, aura-attribute

My lightning component -

```
<aura:component access="GLOBAL" implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:appHostable">
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
    <!-- <ltng:require scripts="/resource/jqueryminjs" afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.doInit}"/> -->
    <aura:attribute name="articleId" type="String" access="global" />
    <forceChatter:feed type="Record" subjectId="{!v.articleId}" />
    <p><b>{!v.articleId}</b></p>
</aura:component>
```

and client controller -

```
({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
        var currentArticleUrl = window.location.href;
        var articleId = helper.getURLParameter('id');

        if (articleId != null) {
            console.log('article Id -->', articleId );
            component.set("v.articleId", articleId);
        }
    }
})
```

Helper code -

```
({
    getURLParameter : function(name) {
        return decodeURIComponent((new RegExp('[?|&]' + name + '=' + '([^&;]+?)(&|#|;|$)').exec(location.search)||[,""])[1].replace(/\+/g, '%20'))||null;
    }
})
```

Article Id is coming from url parameter. So url can be something like-

```
https://domain.lightning.force.com/c/TestKnowledgeArticleApplication.app?id=ka07E0000004IVGQA2
```

I checked that article Id is coming properly on component

tag and client side controller, but the  tag even though using the same attribute does not get the value. I am using this in Napili template component.

Comment: So you mean forceChatter:feed is not working ?

Comment: Yes, for dynamic value. But if I test it with hardcoded values the forceChatter:feed works properly

Comment: Is there a difference in no of digits in Id ?

Comment: Also if you could provide the controller code ,so i can dig into this

Comment: There is no Apex controller, but only client side controller and helper. I have added helper method as well. Id is coming from url itself. Added sample url

Comment: Also no difference in number of digits in the id

Comment: Is it happening for knowledge article only or for other objects as well .

Comment: Behaving same way for account id as well. So most probably something with lightning component and controller communication which is missing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unlike force:recordEdit/reviewView the forceChatter:feed component does not support dynamically changing v.subjectId - I just went and looked and there is no logic in the component to trigger reloading the feed when subjectId changes. The component does have a refreshFeed() method but its not marked access="GLOBAL" so no joy there either. Same for the refresh event handler.

All is not lost though - I would switch to using $A.createComponent() inside of your doInit() to construct the feed dynamically - not hard to do - and then your existing container component will work just fine.

Comment: The forceChatter:feed has numerous bug .It would be helpful if we get some road maps around the fix or alternative so we update our clients making decision .Thanks

Comment: I will give it a try but looks like there is a workaround

Answer (score 2):

Below is the sample code that I got this working

```
<!--c:createComponent-->
<aura:component>
  <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
  <aura:attribute name="articleId" type="String" access="global" />
   <p>Dynamically created Feed</p>
{!v.body}
</aura:component>
```

The component JS controller code

```
/*RecordFeedController.js*/
({
doInit : function(cmp,helper) {
    var currentArticleUrl = window.location.href;
    var articleId = helper.getURLParameter('id');
    $A.createComponent(
        "forceChatter:feed",
        {
            "type": "Record",
            "subjectId": articleId
        },
        function(recordFeed){
            //Add the new button to the body array
            if (cmp.isValid()) {
                var body = cmp.get("v.body");
                body.push(recordFeed);
                cmp.set("v.body", body);
            }
        }
    );
   },
 })
```

[image]

Irrespective of the answer ,this looks not PRODUCTION ready outside lightning experience especially lightning out.There seems to be numerous bug with styling and actions that's noticeable on console outside builders and lightning experience  so avoid using this component in PROD and raise a bug with support so they fix it

Comment: Thanks for the code. UI works perfect with templates inside community but if we try to use it in a normal lightning app then it breaks. so for me using the UI in Napili template works like a charm