# forceChatter:publisher not loading

Tags: lightning-aura-components, community, lightning-apps

I am working on a lightning component where i am using forceChatter:publisher and forceChatter:feed.

I have put this in a component named ChatterCmp. This component is inside RecordViewComponent.

Now, when the RecordViewComponent is triggered via event, this passes object id as attribute to ChatterCmp, and i am using it in the ContextId and RecordId of chatter aura component.

But this is not working.
I have printed the Id, which comes correctly, but because of some reason Chatter components are not accepting those ids.

```
<aura:attribute name="objid" type="string" access="global"/>
<aura:handler event="c:icChatterComponentTrigger" action="{!c.icChatterComponentTrigger}"/>
<forceChatter:publisher context="RECORD" recordId="{!v.objid}" />
<forceChatter:feed type="record" subjectId="{!v.objid}"/>
```

[image]

Am i missing anything here?

Answer (score 4):

I found the solutions:

Unlike force:recordEdit/reviewView the forceChatter:feed component does not support dynamically changing v.subjectId - I just went and looked and there is no logic in the component to trigger reloading the feed when subjectId changes. The component does have a refreshFeed() method but its not marked access="GLOBAL" so no joy there either. Same for the refresh event handler.

All is not lost though - I would switch to using $A.createComponent() inside of your doInit() to construct the feed dynamically - not hard to do - and then your existing container component will work just fine.

```
$A.createComponent(
"forceChatter:publisher", {
    "context": "RECORD",
    "recordId": ideaselected
},
function(recordFeed) {
    //Add the new button to the body array
    if (component.isValid()) {
        var body = component.get("v.body");
        body.push(recordFeed);
        component.set("v.body", body);
    }
}); 

$A.createComponent(
"forceChatter:feed", {
    "type": "Record",
    "subjectId": ideaselected
},
function(recordFeed) {
    //Add the new button to the body array
    if (component.isValid()) {
        var body = component.get("v.body");
        body.push(recordFeed);
        component.set("v.body", body);
    }
});
```

Courtesy: [Lightning component not getting on load value](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/123366/lightning-component-not-getting-on-load-value)

Comment: Bagaria did the approach mentioned above work? Were you able to get the publisher to show anything?

Comment: It worked like charm!! Go for it.